# Drawable xml design is not visible as button background in main xml code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to design a layout which has two buttons, to design these buttons I used drawable xml files as a background. In the android studio, Android studio preview shows

[image]
 these buttons are not visible but genymotion shows these buttons.
The result of running code in genymotion android virtual device

[image]

On the other-hand when I run this code on a real device it doesn't show these buttons.

The result of running code in an android real device

[image]

Drawable xml file code: @drawable/button_design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/navHeadBack"/>
            <corners android:topRightRadius="130dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="130dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="130dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="130dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/navHeadBack" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Activity xml design file code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="@color/commonColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activities.FirstPage">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5.9"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/commonColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/u_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:text="@string/user_sign_in"
            android:textColor="@color/commonColor"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/u_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:text="@string/user_sign_up"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/commonColor"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design_up"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want to make visible / show drawable xml design in the background of these buttons. How can I do this?

**NOTE:** in the xml code when I used `android:enabled="true"`button becomes invisible and when I used `android:enabled="false"` its become visible. But I don't understand why.

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" for both inner LinearLayout. Just check

Comment: when using weights its preferable to set height or width(corresponding to weight) attribute to 0dp

Comment: It is may be your device screen sizes. I will suggest to use `ConstraintLayout`, it will ensure your button positions according to screen sizes

Comment: I tried with `ConstraintLayout` but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/commonColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activities.FirstPage">

      <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo"/>

     <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/u_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:text="@string/user_sign_in"
            android:textColor="@color/commonColor"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/u_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:text="@string/user_sign_up"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/commonColor"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design_up"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />    
    </LinearLayout>      
</LinearLayout>
```

I removed `layout_weight` and make `layout_height="wrap_content"` for child views of `LinearLayout`. Could you try the above layout?. You should correct some dimension. Hope it helps

---

I wrote a simple layout. You can use and edit it to make it as your expected. On the other hand, I guess that the buttons(in your code) are visible on the UI but the background and text color are white. Could you check it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Background is not white bro. Background of one button is **Black** and another is **Red**

Comment: You can enable the [Showing Layout Bounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGqJhK0FTjw) feature on the devices to see where the Views were placed on the UI

Comment: layout placed exactly the same place where I put. but transparent

Comment: Maybe my guess is right. And now you should check  whether `@color/navHeadBack` is white(check all the `colors.xml` files. EX: in the `values` or `values-21` folders)

Comment: I told repeatedly its not white what I set. if it's white why would it shows color in emulator and why not in real device?

Comment: **NOTE:** In the xml code when I used `android:enabled="true"`button becomes invisible and when I used `android:enabled="false"` its become visible. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a RelativeLayout to get the imageview layout_alignParentTop ="true"
and make the button layout_alignParentBottom="true" and remove layout_weight.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do Like This:-

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/commonColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activities.FirstPage">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_contant"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/u_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:text="@string/user_sign_in"
            android:textColor="@color/commonColor"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/u_sign_up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:text="@string/user_sign_up"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/commonColor"
            android:background="@drawable/button_design_up"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `android:layout_height="match_parent"` along with weights.

You need to set `layout_height` to `0dp` to make weights work.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of constrainLayout would solve this issue and usage of ConstrainLayout would remove the nested layout and improve the performance.

This is the sample code that make that design using constrain layout-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl_center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gl_center"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_first"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_first"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_first"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_first"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Try to add some other background color to your second linearlayout so that we can check whether it is the problem with drawable file.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to `android:layout_height="0dp"` both layout while using `android:layout_weight`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/commonColor"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context=".Activities.FirstPage">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="5.9"
    android:background="@color/commonColor"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/logo" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="4.1"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/u_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_design"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:text="@string/user_sign_in"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/commonColor" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/u_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_design_up"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:text="@string/user_sign_up"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/commonColor" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code i have tried below code for custom background.Try this, hope it will work for you

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="60dp" />

<solid android:color="color you want" />
</shape>
```